# Problems setting targetObjectIds

Tags: apex, massemailmessage

I am trying to send a massEmailMessage and I have the following code:

```
List <Id> targetObjectIds = new List <Id> ();

targetObjectIds = [SELECT Id FROM Contact];
System.debug('TargetObjects: ' + targetObjectIds);

Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
mail.setTargetObjectIds(targetObjectIds);
mail.setTemplateID('00Xm0000000QEQ7');
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {mail});
```

When I run this code, then I get the following error:

```
Save error: Illegal assignment from LIST<Contact> to LIST<Id>
```

So I tried changing my code to:

```
List <Contact> targetObjectIds = new List <Contact> ();
```

But then I will get the following error:

```
Saver error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.MassEmailMessage].setTargetObjectIds(LIST<Contact>)
```

I know that the method needs to take a list of Ids, but I am not sure how to get a list of Ids from the contact object.

Tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just populate a List with the retrieved data and use it for your `setTargetObjectIds` method.

```
List <Id> targetObjectIds = new List <Id> ();
List <Contact> targetObjects = new List <Contact> ();

targetObjects = [SELECT Id FROM Contact];
for(Contact cnt : targetObjects)
   targetObjectIds.add(cnt.Id);

Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
mail.setTargetObjectIds(targetObjectIds);
```

Comment: It's pleasure for me to help you @user8737