# Help with SOQL query over 3 objects

Tags: soql

I am having problems creating a SOQL query over my 3 objects.

Contact, Patient and Disease

Patient and Disease are in a Master Detail relationship, where Disease is the Master

Contact is a Lookup field in Patient.

So, the query that I need is:
Select Id from Contact, where patient is that contact and has disease x

I need this query to populate the list targetObjects in this code:

```
List <Id> targetObjectIds = new List <Id> ();
List <Contact> targetObjects = new List <Contact> ();

targetObjects = [SELECT Id FROM Contact];
for(Contact cnt : targetObjects) {
  targetObjectIds.add(cnt.Id);
}

Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
mail.setTargetObjectIds(targetObjectIds);
```

Tia.

Comment: Can you please describe your question with an example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Contact` is a Lookup for `Patient`, relevant `Contact` id is available at `Patient` object itself. So something like below should work. This is for going from child to parent
`SELECT Contact__c FROM Patient__c WHERE Disease__c = 'your_val'`

This is for going from parent to child
`SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Contact__c FROM Patient__r) FROM Disease__c` 
Apply your naming conventions where it's required.
If you are facing with **can not understand the relationship** error better to check the correct `API` name by generating the WSDL (Name > Setup > Develop > API > Generate Enterprise WSDL).

Comment: I have tried something similar before, but I always get the error that it doesn't understand the relationship Patient__r.

Comment: This is because you haven't given the correct relationship name. see my update

Comment: So, I am now using the first query, which gets me what I want. However, I need to get the ID from the Contact Object as I will pass it to massemailmessage settargetobjectids and that only accepts ids from contacts and leads etc. is it possible to change the query somehow so that i will end up selecting the id from contact? thanks

Comment: Since the `Contact` object is a lookup for `Patient` object it's always having Id of the relevant `Contact` in `Patient` object. So when you use `Contact__c` field value of `Patient` object it's giving the same `Id` field value of `Contact` object. You can use that list for your method

Comment: Strange, as when my code is triggered, I get the following message in salesforce: Error:Apex trigger emailTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: EmailTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Only contacts, leads and users allowed for targetObjectIds.: []: Class.TriggerHandler.afterUpdateWorkflowActions: line 34, column 1

Comment: Is it possible to write something like:
SELECT Id, (SELECT Email__c from Patient__c) FROM Contact WHERE Disease__r = "x"
I do get errors with this queries, but this the kind of query I need I think...

Comment: Can you update your question with the code how you are populating the Ids before calling that method? I believe you are following the method described in http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40751/problems-setting-targetobjectids

Comment: Yes, I will update the question here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15152/discussion-between-highfive-and-user8737).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select (Select Contact__c From Patient__r)
From Disease__c s 
WHERE Disease__c.Name == 'Disease X'
```

**Note:** Contact could be __c or just Contact.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, but I need to select from Contact. In this example I am selecting from Patient__r and from Disease__c. So the ID I am getting in the end will be from the contact object.

Comment: You are querying the COntact IDs.

Give it a try on either workbench or force.com IDE.

You are getting the IDs of COntacts where Patients are looking up that has a master of Disease = Disease X

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to query from the Patient object, try this:

```
for (Patient__c pat : [ SELECT
                            Id,
                            Disease__c,
                            Disease__c.Name,
                            Contact__c
                        FROM
                            Patient__c
                        WHERE
                            Disease__c.Name = 'Some Disease'    
                        LIMIT
                            1000    ]) {

    targetObjectIds.add(pat.Contact__c);                            
}
```